# Converting Java crypto code to NodeJS

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

I am working on implementing the [Walmart API](https://developer.walmartapis.com/#authentication) in NodeJS. Walmart only provides JAVA examples. I am having issues getting it right. My signature is a bit longer and not accepted when compared to using the Java executable they provide.

I'd appreciate any help. Even figuring out what format the Walmart provided secret is would help.

Here's working Java code:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;

public class SHA256WithRSAAlgo {
    private static String consumerId = "b68d2a72....";   // Trimmed for security reason
    private static String baseUrl = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v2/feeds";
    private static String privateEncodedStr = "MIICeAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAA......";       //Trimmed for security reasons
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String httpMethod = "GET";
        String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String stringToSign = consumerId + "\n" +
                                baseUrl + "\n" +
                                httpMethod + "\n" +
                                timestamp + "\n";
        String signedString = SHA256WithRSAAlgo.signData(stringToSign, privateEncodedStr);
        System.out.println("Signed String: " + signedString);
    }
    public static String signData(String stringToBeSigned, String encodedPrivateKey) {
        String signatureString = null;
        try {
            byte[] encodedKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedPrivateKey);
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKeyBytes);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey myPrivateKey = kf.generatePrivate(privSpec);
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            signature.initSign(myPrivateKey);
            byte[] data = stringToBeSigned.getBytes("UTF-8");
            signature.update(data);
            byte[] signedBytes = signature.sign();
            signatureString = Base64.encodeBase64String(signedBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return signatureString;
    }
}
```

Here's my Node code:

```
const PK_HEADER = '\n-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
const PK_FOOTER = '\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'

const consumerId = 'b68d2a72....'  
const baseUrl = 'https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v2/feeds'
const privateEncodedStr = 'MIICeAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAA......'      

const privateKey = `${PK_HEADER}${config.walmart.secret}${PK_FOOTER}`

const privateEncodedKey = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'base64')
const timestamp = Date.now()

const stringToSign = consumerId + '\n' +
                     baseUrl + '\n' +
                     httpMethod + '\n' +
                     timestamp + '\n'

const sign = createSign('RSA-SHA256')
sign.update(stringToSign)
const signedString = sign.sign(privateKey, 'hex')

console.log(signedString)
```

Some notes. I tried passing the `privateEncodedStr` as is but Crypto balks at not having the PEM headers so I had to add those.

Using the same timestamp the Java code yielded something like:

```
bhG0q4Es7iOJtBvepJ2Ao6zPRllf6nM+026dgEadPcaYDdIoCQBYxWWSXB16XcQXgCDcqZ1PW2xgAavHC57jchSXtsTYkuXcWBavQGTH+5YonxIJCzI0wimVKKbqtocKvz4sngXKvIDP7wKKUdXOT6zXVYOdjLfUTERTs7RVg=
```

My JS code:

```
219af9f3048ccef558d6ddeeb61d19ed8a968ade5125760d81717dbd62e8447dd831b123a52624d56bc35aef1b082c29585e6fece2aba0fb7853d6840f45e724489028415a9eab8a51e48037a5884f5a12a238ed61a16003e1c412f873d3cfd2f6336dec8c262b01c3ba2a234f0979b8073f096cd35c7d1425bbcfc4603ff05b
```

Here's what the Walmart secret looks kinda like:

```
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
```

Any idea what format this is? It appears to be a [private key](http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/) with the headers/footers removed.

Comment: this is a bit unrelated but if you do figure it out would you be able to post on github? cheers!

Comment: Your resulting JS string seems to be an hex byte sequence, while the Java generated one is encoded in `base64`. Try `console.log(new Buffer(signedString, 'hex').toString('base64'))`

Comment: @karuzo you're my hero! that was it. Would you post that as the answer please.

Comment: Turns out that just changing the 'hex' to 'base64' was all I needed to do. Thanks for catching that

Comment: Ok, I've posted an updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is right, you just need to output `signedString` in the proper format, which is `base64`.

Just change:

`const signedString = sign.sign(privateKey, 'hex');`

To:

`const signedString = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');`

And there you go.

Comment: And here's the Gist https://gist.github.com/cyberwombat/bc22fcd44037b7f8c1920432636f9cd5